# Respond different html if it's not ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I asked this before and I have got several negative scores but this time I ask it more clear.

I have this structure on a website:

- Mainpage (All resources and scripts are in this page)

  - All Other pages (HTML just contains elements of that specific page)

If user clicks on mainpage anchors to other pages, AJAX function that is embed to `On click event` will run and URL address will change using `Window.history.PushState` .

The problem is what we can do if user enters URL of other pages instead clicking on anchors? For example if user enters: http://example.com/pages/about
then only elements of that page will load without resources and scripts of mainpage that is needed.

I think to a solution something like this:

1. Detect if user enters URL instead clicking on anchors.(detect HTTP request)
2. Load resources included in mainpage if it is a HTTP request.

Could this solution be in Client-side(javascript) way? I know a little PHP too.

Take a look at Cloudflare panel to see what i mean: https://www.cloudflare.com/a/overview

Comment: It will not work if the visitor has javascript turned off so you should do it in PHP with .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I actually created something to address this very issue for a designer friend and put it on GitHub. Maybe you can use it or it will give you ideas... https://github.com/timgavin/tinyTemplate

Comment: @timgavin : It looks pretty cool Tim. But if I want to use a template engine, I should change my markup and website structure as you wrote in your project's documentation. For my current project I prefer a fallback solution just for current problem.

Comment: This should help: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little research(Thanks to comments) and this is my preferable solution. I didn't want to change markup so Template engines wasn't my choice.

1.Write this PHP Script in save it in a PHP file.

```
<?php

/* Detect AJAX */

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* If it is AJAX do this */
}

else {
/* If it is not AJAX do this; In my case I did echo all scripts and resources that I wanted to be in AJAX addresses */
    echo '
        <script src="example.js"></script>
    ';
}
```

2.Link above PHP script file in pages that have both AJAX and HTTP request. In my case I put that is all other pages instead Main-page.

```
<?php include "../script.php"; ?>
```

3.Config your webserver to support PHP scripts in HTML file extension. My webserver was Apache so I wrote this line in .htaccess file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```